# Java applet on an SSL page with link to jnpl file

Tags: java, ssl, applet

I'm having a weird SSL issue.  I have a dynamically generated page which contains a Java applet linking to a dynamically generated JNPL file. The applet does what it is suppose to do. This all works.

The issue is with the SSL certificate.  Browsers have no problem with the certificate looking at static pages or with the dynamically generated page. Only the client side complains when the Java stuff starts that the 'Publisher authenticity can not be verified."

The issue goes away when I use a non-SSL URL to the JNPL file. Is there a work-around for this issue? I'd like to go SSL all the way.

And my jar is code-signed.

Thanks

Comment: @AndrewThompson java network launching protocol - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start

Comment: That is ***[JNLP](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jnlp/info)***.  Please order the letters more carefully and edit your post.  BTW - the best information on JWS can be found right [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Answer (score 2):

This error comes when your ssl-certificate was issued from a root-certificate that is not in the java-truststore but is in the browsers truststore.

you can check which certificate-issuers are trusted in your java-vm by using the keytool (comes with the jdk afaik) the truststore for java is usually installed in jre/lib/security

```
keytool --list -keystore cacerts
```

lists all certificates that are included in the keystore

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I understand your comment. However, I can't add the root-certificate to all clients world wide. :-) so this is a no-go.

Comment: @kib So get your signing certificate signed by a CA.

Comment: or get a new certificat by a ca thats trusted by java